# Is there a difference between "can" and "could" when referring to the future?

Tags: grammar

I was wondering which of the following sentences is grammatically correct.

> He should study hard every day so that he **could** leave past his everyday life.

or:

> He should study hard every day so that he **can** leave past his everyday life.

Comment: Neither one, unfortunately. The phrase _leave past his everyday life_ is ungrammatical and confusing. If you leave out _past_, the second one is OK, and the first one is not idiomatic English, but not ungrammatical. The reason has nothing to do with the future tense, however, since there is no future tense in English. Modal auxiliaries, however, are every bit as challenging as complex and imaginary tenses.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Neither one, unfortunately. The phrase *leave past his everyday life* is ungrammatical and confusing. If you leave out *past*, the second one is OK, and the first one is not idiomatic English, but not ungrammatical. The reason has nothing to do with the future tense, however, since there is no future tense in English. Modal auxiliaries, however, are every bit as challenging as complex and imaginary tenses.